# Very strange behaviour with sampler handling using OpenGL and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, glsles

I have implemented cubemap shadow mapping successfully with just one point light.

To render this scene I use in the first render pass geometry shaders to dispatch the 6 frustrums. In the second render pass I use samplerCubeShadow in the fragment shader to computer the shadow factor.

I have OpenGL/GLSL version 4.40 with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

But now I want to implement multiple cubemap shadow mapping to render shadows using several point lights.

Here's some peace of code from my fragment shader:

```
[...]

/*
** Shadow Cube sampler array.
*/
uniform samplerCubeShadow ShadowCubeSampler[5]; //Max point light by scene = 5

[...]

float ConvertDistToClipSpace(vec3 lightDir_ws)
{
    vec3 AbsVec = abs(lightDir_ws);
    float LocalZcomp = max(AbsVec.x, max(AbsVec.y, AbsVec.z));

    float NormZComp = (NearFar.y + NearFar.x)/(NearFar.y - NearFar.x)
        - (2.0f * NearFar.y * NearFar.x)/(LocalZcomp * NearFar.y - NearFar.x);

    return ((NormZComp + 1) * 0.5f);
}

float GetCubeShadowFactor(vec3 vertexPosition_ws, float shadowFactor, int idx)
{
    vec3 lightToVertexDir_ws = vertexPosition_ws - LightPos_ws.xyz;
    float LightToVertexClipDist = ConvertDistToClipSpace(lightToVertexDir_ws);

    float LightToOccluderClipDist = texture(
        ShadowCubeSampler[idx], vec4(lightToVertexDir_ws, LightToVertexClipDist));

    if (LightToOccluderClipDist < LightToVertexClipDist)
    {
        shadowFactor = 0.0f;
    }
    return (shadowFactor);
}

void main(void)
{
    [...]

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 1; idx++) //Test first with 1 point light
    {
        float ShadowFactor = GetCubeShadowFactor(Position_ws.xyz, ShadowFactor, idx);
    }
    [...]
}
```

The problem is I have the error 1282 (INVALID_OPERATION). To resume the situation here, I want to display exactly the same scene like in the picture above with a SINGLE point light but this time using an array of samplerCubeShadow. What is amazing is if I replace the first parameter of the function 'texture' 'ShadowCubeSampler[idx]' by 'ShadowCubeSampler[0]' is works! However the value of 'idx' is always '0'. I tried the following code without success:

```
int toto = 0;

float LightToOccluderClipDist = texture(ShadowCubeSampler[toto], vec4(lightToVertexDir_ws, LightToVertexClipDist));
```

I already have the error 1282! The type of the index is the same (int)!

I have already use arrays of 'sampler2DShadow' or 'sampler2D' without problem.

So, Why it does not work correctly using 'samplerCubeShadow' and the solution 'ShadowCubeSampler[0]' works and not the others ?

PS: If I define an array of 2 and if I use 2 cubemaps so 2 point lights, it works. So, if I load a number of cubemaps inferior to the number specified in the fragment shader it fails!

I have no compilation error and no linkage error. Here's the code I use to check shader programs state:

```
void video::IEffectBase::Log(void) const
{
    GLint errorLink = 0;

    glGetProgramiv(this->m_Handle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &errorLink);

    if (errorLink != GL_TRUE)
    {
        GLint sizeError = 0;

        glGetProgramiv(this->m_Handle, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &sizeError);

        char *erreur = new char[sizeError + 1];

        glGetShaderInfoLog(this->m_Handle, sizeError, &sizeError, erreur);

        erreur[sizeError] = '\0';

        std::cerr << erreur << std::endl;

        glDeleteProgram(this->m_Handle);

        delete[] erreur;
    }
}
```

And about the texture unit limits:

```
std::cout << GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS << std::endl;
std::cout << GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS << std::endl;

$> 35660
$> 34930
```

If I use 'ShadowCubeSampler[0]', '0' written directly in the code I have the same display like the picture a the beginning of the my post without error. If I use 'ShadowCubeSampler[idx]' with idx = 0 I have the following display:

[image]

As you can see, all the geometry sharing this shader has not been rendered. However I don't have any linkage error. How can you explain that ? Is it possible the system unlink the shader program?

**UPDATE**

Let's suppose my array of samplerCubeShadow can contain 2 maximum samplers (uniform samplerCubeShadow tex_shadow[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOM4K.jpg)).

I noticed if I load just one point light, so one cubemap:

```
CASE 1

uniform samplerCubeShadow tex_shadow[1]; //MAX POINT LIGHT = 1
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {tex_shadow[i];} //OK
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {texture(tex_shadow[i], ...);} //OK
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {texture(tex_shadow[0], ...);} //OK

CASE 2

uniform samplerCubeShadow tex_shadow[2]; //MAX POINT LIGHT = 2
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {tex_shadow[i];} //NOT OK - 1282
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {texture(tex_shadow[i], ...);} //NOT OK - 1282
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {texture(tex_shadow[0], ...);} //OK

CASE 3

uniform samplerCubeShadow tex_shadow[2]; //MAX POINT LIGHT = 2
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {tex_shadow[i];} //OK
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {texture(tex_shadow[i], ...);} //OK
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {texture(tex_shadow[0], ...);} //OK
```

Conclusion: if the max number of sampler is equal to the number of sampler loaded, I can loop over the samplers contained in my array. If the number is inferior, it does not work! I can use a maximum of 32 texture units for each use of shader program. I have the same problem using the samplerCube keyword.

It's very strange because I don't have any problem using sampler2D or sampler2DShadow for spot light shadow computation.

I check with NSight where I put a break point in the fragment shader file and of course the break point is neaver reached. It's like the shader program is not linked but it's not the case.

Do you think it could be a problem concerning cubeMap samplers in general or the problem comes from the cubemap initialization ?

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: What version of OpenGL/GLSL are you targeting? Arrays of samplers are very special in GLSL. The above code might work with GL 4.0 / GLSL 400, but definitively not before that.

Comment: Invalid operation is probably because the GLSL program you are trying to use didn't link. Can you include the output of the shader info logs and program info log?

Comment: I currently use OpenGL/GLSL 4.40. I have the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M. I don't have any compilation error and no linkage error. I use glGetProgramiv(this->m_Handle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status) and the variable status is always equal to 1. But when the scene is rendered all the geometry which must be rendered by this shader program is not displayed. In my case all the boxes and the plane are not displayed. How can you explain that the instruction 'ShadowCubeSampler[0]' works and 'ShadowCubeSampler[idx]' with idx = 0 not ? It's crazy! I have never seen a such thing before.

Comment: I have updated my post. Maybe you will have a better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have never use an array inside of glsl and infortuntly i dont have the equipments now to do so,
but have you tried using an unsigned int uint in glsl.

```
float GetCubeShadowFactor(vec3 vertexPosition_ws, float shadowFactor, uint idx) {
....
}
```

also note that you cannot use infinite samplers in you shaders.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I've already tried to use uint type and it's always the same error! I don't understand what infinite sampler is? In my case I accept 5 samplerCubeShadow in my array.

Comment: what i mean is a lot, because my gpu can handle only four samplers at a time for example.

Comment: I have updated my post. The variables GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS and GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS give the results 34930 and 35660. What does it mean exactly ? The number of texture (samplers) I can use within a shader program?

Comment: @user1364743: Those aren't the values you want. They are enums used to query the values. Use for example `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, ...)` to get the maximum number of texture units.

Comment: Ok. The result for me is 32 texture image units. Is a texture cube one texture unit or 6 texture units ? I think it's one because I use just one glActiveTexture... So 32 is sufficient and I don't think my problem comes from the max number of texture units. What do you think about that?

Comment: A cubemap texture is bound to 1 texture image unit. It is an array texture with 6 images for all intents and purposes, but array textures are only bound to 1 location no matter how many images they contain.

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation. I have updated my post. Maybe you will have a better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL has, depending on the targeted version, special restrictions on arrays of opaque types (textures are one of them). Before OpenGL 4 looping over such arrays is not possible. You can check the details here: [OpenGL Wiki - Data Types](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Opaque_arrays)

Comment: I use Opengl/GLSL version 4.40. So, I can loop over an array of samplers.